# Куча div'ов на одной странице - это нормально?

Tags: веб-дизайн, html

Я просто новичок в собрании сайтов, а на страницах у меня куча дивов. Так это нормально или я что то не так делаю?

Comment: куча - это сколько? без кода трудно сказать

Comment: ну скажу так, что каждая область - див. Так и должно быть?

Comment: я думаю, что да

Comment: На самом деле не факт. Киньте сюда пример страницы, все станет яснее, так как одно дело — много смысловых блоков, и другое — сложнуе конструкции из дивов, которые можно упростить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что вы называете кучей. 
А вообще все познается в сравнении. Проведите небольшой эксперимент: зайдите на несколько сайтов, откройте консоль браузера, вбейте туда

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').length
```

и наслаждайтесь результатами. 
В частности, для hascode.ru у меня получилось 883 div'а, для habrahabr.ru - 372, для lenta.ru - 280, для ru.wikipedia.org - 104, для championat.com - 504 штуки. Думаю, это немаленькие цифры (хотя разброс довольно существенный), но, как видите, проблем с ними у браузеров не возникает. 
P.S. Сайты выбраны мною совершенно случайно - всего лишь те, которые я просматривал в течение последнего получаса

Comment: Думаю, стОит учитывать и другие контейнеры типа span, p. 
Браузер скорее будет тормозить от JS, в крайнем случае от "веса" страницы, но очень вряд ли  от количества блоков. 10-мегабайтная страница с одним единственным div-ом, кучей галерей, попапов, скролл- и ховер-эффектов и простыней текста - самый наглядный пример-ответ на заданый в шапке вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Правда сейчас появляются семантические теги в HTML5 - которые заменяют часть дивов. Однако если ими не пользуетесь то все логически разбивается именно дивами